# Graphing data that is read using readHTMLTable

Tags: r

I want to read the following table , from a webpage then create a bargraph.

> Language............ Jobs
>
> PHP....................          12,664
>
> Java...................          12,558
>
> Objective C.........  8,925
>
> SQL....................           5,165
>
> Android (Java)....    4,981
>
> Ruby...................           3,859
>
> JavaScript........... 3,742
>
> C#.......................         3,549
>
> C++.....................          1,908
>
> ActionScript......... 1,821
>
> Python.................           1,649
>
> C..........................           1,087
>
> ASP.NET...............            818

My questions:

1.The problem that my bars get messed up and each bar does correspond to the correct language
The following is my code:

```
library(XML)
tables2 <-(readHTMLTable("http://www.sitepoint.com/best-programming-language-of-2013/",which=1))
barplot(as.numeric(tables2$Job),names.arg=tables2$Language)
```

1. Since I am a beginner at R I would like to know in what format does `readHTMLTable` save the data in? is it a matrix, data frame or other format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that `Jobs` is being read as a `factor`. Because of the commas in that field, you can't do a direct numeric conversion. You can find out what 'format' your object is in R by doing `str()`. Here `str(tables2)` gives:

```
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Language: Factor w/ 13 levels "ActionScript",..: 10 7 9 13 2 12 8 5 6 1 ...
 $ Jobs    : Factor w/ 13 levels "1,087","1,649",..: 6 5 12 11 10 9 8 7 4 3 ...
```

So you can see `Jobs` is a factor, and that `tables2` is a `data.frame`. To convert it to numeric you need to remove the commas. You can do that with `gsub()`.

```
tables2$Jobs <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",tables2$Jobs))
```

No `str(tables2)` gives:

```
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Language: Factor w/ 13 levels "ActionScript",..: 10 7 9 13 2 12 8 5 6 1 ...
 $ Jobs    : num  12664 12558 8925 5165 4981 ...
```

and when you do your plot, all should be well:

```
barplot(tables2$Jobs,names.arg=tables2$Language)
```

[image]